# IF with different cells conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 5 columns with different values A1 as v1 (voucher 1), A2 as v2, ... , A5 as Bulk (there must be at least 1 value, and sometimes there are 2 or more).
I want to show it in 1 cell (A6).

If there's a value in one of those cell, there must be value like "v1 has A1*1000" the 1000 is fixed. v2 until v5 has different value (not like 1000 until 5000 thing)

I already tried if condition. but if there's already a value in one of those cell, then the function stopped there

```
=IF(A2<>"";"you got v1="&A2;IF(B2<>"";"you got v2="&B2;IF(C2<>"";"you got v3="&C2;IF(D2<>"";"you got v4="&D2;IF(E2<>"";"you got bulk="&E2;"")))))
```

Expected output:

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this Formula Instead in `E2`

```
=CONCAT(IF(A2<>"","You got V1 = " & A2,),IF(B2<>"","You got V2 = " & B2,),IF(C2<>"","You got V3 = " & C2,),IF(D2<>"","You got V4 = " & D2,),IF(E2<>"","You got Bulk = " & E2,))
```